# Java Bitmap RLE8 format

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio, image-compression, run-length-encoding

Does Java ImageIO (or any other image handlers) support BI_RLE8 image format? The only thing I have managed to find is [BMPImageWriteParam](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/bmp/BMPImageWriteParam.html) but I have no idea whatsoever how to use that.
Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Use `setCompressionType()` with the type you want. All 4 types listed are supported as stated in the documentation

Comment: I have removed your "thank you"-note and new question. You express thanks by upvoting helpful answers and accepting the best answer. If you have a new or follow-up question, please create a new question; if you think it is relevant, add a link back to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this example](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#advanced-usage) for how to write using `ImageWriter` and using `ImageWriteParam` (use an instance of `BMPImageWriteParam` in your case). Scroll a bit down to find the write example.

Instead of the line:

```
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
```

You should insert something like:

```
BMPImageWriteParam param = new BMPImageWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("BI_RLE8");
```

You can safely pass `null` for thumbnails and metadata (`...` in the example).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save an image using custom parameters, you have to use an [`ImageWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html) to which you can pass custom parameters to write the output file.

You can get the params from an `ImageWriter` using its [`getDefaultWriteParam()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#getDefaultWriteParam--) method where you can set the compression type. You don't even have to cast it to [`BMPImageWriteParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/bmp/BMPImageWriteParam.html) because setting the compression type is available via the [`ImageWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html) super interface.

Note that in order to use a custom compression type, you have to set the compression mode to [`ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#MODE_EXPLICIT).

Here is the complete code:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(200, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);

ImageWriter writer  = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("bmp").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("BI_RLE8");

writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(new File("test.bmp")));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bi, null, null), param);
writer.dispose();
```

Note that `BI_RLE8` compression is not available for all types of [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)s.
For exmaple `BI_RLE8` compression is supported for `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` and `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` but it is not supported for `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` in which case an `IOException` will be thrown by the `ImageWriter.write()` method (which is actually `BMPImageWriter.write()`).